Relative spherical angles from 2 camera poses
Given 2 4x4 matrices representing 2 camera poses, I can get the relative camera transformation by
M = torch.inverse(p1).mm(p2)

How can I further calculate the relative rotation and translation (phi, theta and radius) from 1 camera to another?

Assuming that both of these camera poses are in the same reference frame, then M in your case will be the transformation matrix between the two cameras. The translation will be the first column of the transformation matrix with an XYZ. The other values in the 4x4 matrix are the rotation matrix, which describes the rotation between the two camera poses. I have more experience with using NumPy, but the following is how you would extract the translation vector and the rotation matrix.
import numpy as np

# Compute the relative transformation matrix
M = np.linalg.inv(p1) @ p2

translation_vector = M[:3, 3]
rotation_matrix = M[:3, :3]

Generally I leave it as a 3x3 rotation matrix or convert it to euler angles (radians) which looks like [theta_x, theta_y, theta_z]. Which can be done with the following:
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

euler_angles = R.from_matrix(rotation_matrix).as_euler('xyz', degrees=False)

I am not complete certain on converting the translation to (phi, theta and radius) as I normally leave it as is. I did find this post in which you can see how do find these though. Faster numpy cartesian to spherical coordinate conversion?
